# Android OpenGL Error

Tags: java, android, netbeans, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to OpenGL and Android and my code is not working and I don't know why. I don't know how to debug the code with Netbeans and AVD (android 4.0.3), so I ask for your help.

```
package com.egg.game.test;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class glTriangle {

private int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private static int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
private int vertexStride = Float.SIZE * COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private int vertexCount;
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private float[] color;
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;"
        + "void main() {"
        + "  gl_Position = vPosition;"
        + "}";
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;"
        + "uniform vec4 vColor;"
        + "void main() {"
        + "  gl_FragColor = vColor;"
        + "}";

public glTriangle() {

    color = new float[]{.5f, .2f, 0f, 1.0f};

    vertexCount = 3;

    vertexBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(Float.SIZE * COORDS_PER_VERTEX * vertexCount);
    float[] buffer = vertexBuffer.array();
    buffer[0] = 0f;
    buffer[1] = 0f;
    buffer[2] = 0f;
    buffer[3] = 1f;
    buffer[4] = 0f;
    buffer[5] = 0f;
    buffer[6] = 0f;
    buffer[7] = 1f;
    buffer[8] = 0f;


    int vertexShader = GameRederer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = GameRederer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
}

public void draw() {
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle,
            COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            vertexStride,
            vertexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
```

I Changed the buffer code to this:

```
    vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Float.SIZE * COORDS_PER_VERTEX * vertexCount).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.put(10f);
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.put(10f);
    vertexBuffer.put(0f);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

Now i don't get any error but!!!! my triangle didn't get draw!

Comment: Don't take this as a rude comment, but... if you don't know _how to debug_ the code, maybe you should try find out why?

Comment: As J.Steen suggested, you should really be able to debug your code. If you don't know how to debug your code with the IDE of your choice, you should consider switching your IDE! Why are you using Netbeans? I never worked with Netbeans, but for Android development, I would recommend Eclipse (especially if you are new to this). There are lots of (official) tutorials for Android development using Eclipse and it has a decent debugger which is very simple to use!

Comment: I agree to kroneml, eclipse works like a charm, and debugging is very pleasant with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate floats in your FloatBuffer and convert them to a array.
Then you populate your array, but not your FloatBuffer, maybe this is the error.

```
float[] buffer = new float[] {
...
};
vertexBuffer.put(buffer);
vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

I'm not sure, maybe .array() returns a changeable reference, maybe it clones the data.
Just try it!

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know.

Comment: I seams the AVD cant run opengl and i have to run the code on a real device. So... i am installing eclipse to run the android plugin to test again!

Comment: AVD can run OpenGL in the new version, edit your virtual device, and under hardware features, add "GPU emulation" and set it to "true", it sometimes crashes, but it works

Comment: i now get the situation i describe upstairs in my post... no errors but the triangle didn't get draw!!

Comment: Finally i have to change this code: `private int vertexStride = Float.SIZE * COORDS_PER_VERTEX;`   to this other one:  `private int vertexStride = Float.SIZE/8 * COORDS_PER_VERTEX;`.... a and fix a vertex so i get draw a real triangle... thansk a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @Enriquillo Since float has always 4 bytes, you can use `private int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;`